# ¿Como puedo llamar a un componente polymer propio en otro componente polymer?

Tags: git, polymer

Estoy haciendo un proyecto Polymer 3 y quisiera que desde el componente  (por poner un ejemplo), pueda llamar a mi componente . Cada uno de ellos lo tengo separado y con su propio repositorio.

Comment: Sería bueno que nos muestres algo de lo que has probado para poder entender qué te falta y cómo ayudarte mejor. Te sugiero leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero recomendarte que actualices los components usando lit-element, ya es la evolución de Polymer.

Para usar un componente dentro del tuyo o de cualquier otro proyecto es tan fácil como importarlo y usarlo:

Importarlo en un HTML:

```
<script type="module" src="node_modules/@polymer/paper-button/paper-button.js"></script>
```

Dentro de tu componente lo importarías así:

```
import '@polymer/paper-button';
```

Y para usarlo, como sabes sería directamente con el custom element creado:

```
<paper-button raised class="indigo">raised</paper-button>
```

Más información: https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction#how-do-i-use-a-web-component-

Answer (score -1):

Primero tienes que instalar tu componente que tienes en tu repositorio al igual que instalas cualquier otro componente solo que en lugar de PolymerElements/paper-button sería con tu usuario de Git y el nombre de tu componente usergit/my-component y lo usas justo como comenta Jorge aunque solo como aclaración lit-element es una forma de crear componentes nativos, Polymer ya es una librería de web components no es que sea la evolución buena de otra.

Comment: Hola @YhoshuaOchoa. Antes que nada, te sugiero revisar la sección [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). No siempre todas las preguntas se deben responder, por lo menos, hasta que sean mas claras.

Comment: Yo respondo una duda e inquietud de alguien, no hay una forma ni guía especifica que te diga cuando puedes o no tratar de ayudar a alguien.

Comment: Esa es tu opinión, pero la realidad es que en ESTE FORO si que hay una forma y guía específica, y está en la sección [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), que sugiero que revises.